# Reverse forwarding - in a way

Tags: android

Is it possible to create android applications that can communicate with apps running on the computer through USB? Like some sort of reverse "adb forward".

Answer (score 1):

it's possible using the adb interface. I'm not sure about the specifics, but there are apps that do it. One example would be [PDAnet](http://www.junefabrics.com/android/).